# PHP define global variables for functions?

Tags: php

I want to create an array which is in my function.php code definded so I do not have to transfer the array through my hole code. But it won't work...

This is an example of my function.php:

```
<?php
define("titleArray", array());

function foo(){
echo $this->titleArray;
}

function boo(){
array_push($this->titleArray, "Hello");
}
```

But it doesn't work... How can I fix that so that every function has access to the array?

Greetings

Comment: Are you actually using classes in your real code? If so, make your title array a class property, then it's available to every method in that class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you store your array globally using the `$GLOBALS`, and instead of using `echo` to print an **array**, use the `print_r` method instead.

```
<?php
  $GLOBALS["titleArray"]  = array('world');

  function foo(){
    print_r($GLOBALS["titleArray"]);
}

function boo(){
  array_push($GLOBALS["titleArray"], "Hello");

  print_r($GLOBALS["titleArray"]);
}

foo();
boo();
```

Comment: And if I edit the array e.g. in `boo()` and I call another function after that, that function is also dealing with that edited array by `boo()` or is it again only filled with "world"?

Comment: Yes because the array is declared globally, any changes made, would also be reflected by other methods that use the global array.

Answer (score 1):

just remove `$this`

```
<?php
define("titleArray", array());

function foo(){
echo titleArray;
}

function boo(){
array_push(titleArray, "Hello");
}
```

note that array values are allowed after php 7.0 version

Answer (score 1):

Generally we use `define` to make constant value which never updates, use class instead

```
 <?php
   class abc {
   $titleArray = [];
   function foo(){
     echo $this->titleArray;
   }

   function boo(){
     array_push($this->titleArray, "Hello");
   }
 }
```

The define() function defines a constant. Constants are much like variables, except for the following differences: A constant's value cannot be changed after it is set.

Comment: Dear readers NEVER use OOP unless you absolutely have to, and never for something so trivial

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do it:

- use `global` in every function
- declare `$GLOBALS[]` once outside the function

```
$titleArray = [];
// $GLOBALS['titleArray'] = [];

function foo(){
    global $titleArray;
    print_r($titleArray);
    // print_r($GLOBALS['titleArray']);
}

function boo(){
    global $titleArray;
    array_push($this->titleArray, "Hello");
    // array_push($GLOBALS['titleArray'], "Hello");
}
```